# Why am I still getting Yahoo bounce back errors?

Tags: php

I'm getting yahoo bounceback errors when submitting a test email in my form using a yahoo email address and sending to a gmail address.

I know that yahoo throws errors when using the phpmailer "FROM", but what I've read online, including here, says to use "SETFROM".  The email is sent, but the from is blank.  How can I still pass in the users email and send him a copy of the form?  I'm currently using a bcc to send him a copy of the email.

```
<?php
session_start();

include("php/simple-php-captcha/simple-php-captcha.php");
include("php/php-mailer/class.phpmailer.php");


// Step 1 - Enter your email address below.
$to = 'info@novawebdev.com';

$arrResult = array('response'=>'');

if(isset($_POST['emailSent'])) {

    $subject = 'RTO Camera Application';

    // Step 2 - If you don't want a "captcha" verification, remove that IF.
    if (strtolower($_POST["captcha"]) == strtolower($_SESSION['captcha']['code'])) {

        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $business_name = $_POST['business_name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $merchantid = $_POST['merchantid'];

        // Step 3 - Configure the fields list that you want to receive on the email.
    $fields = array(
        0 => array(
            'text' => 'First Name',
            'val' => $_POST['first_name']
        ),
        1 => array(
            'text' => 'Last Name',
            'val' => $_POST['last_name']
        ),
        2 => array(
            'text' => 'Business Name',
            'val' => $_POST['business_name']
        ),
        3 => array(
            'text' => 'Phone Number',
            'val' => $_POST['phone']
        ),
        4 => array(
            'text' => 'Email',
            'val' => $_POST['email']
        ),
        5 => array(
            'text' => 'Merchant ID',
            'val' => $_POST['merchantid']
        )
    );

    $message = "";

    // foreach($fields as $field) {
        // $message .= $field['text'].": " . htmlspecialchars($field['val'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
    // }

$mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->IsSMTP();

    // Step 4 - If you don't receive the email, try to configure the parameters below:

    //$mail->Host = 'mail.yourserver.com';                // Specify main and backup server
    //$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             // Enable SMTP authentication
    //$mail->Username = 'username';                       // SMTP username
    //$mail->Password = 'secret';                         // SMTP password
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                          // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

    $mail->SetFrom($email, $first_name, $last_name);
    $mail->FromName = $_POST['first_name'].' '.$_POST['last_name'];
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email, $first_name, $last_name);
    $mail->AddBCC($email);
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $message;  

    if($mail->Send()) {
       $arrResult['response'] = 'success';
    } else {
        $arrResult['response'] = 'error';
    }

} else {

    $arrResult['response'] = 'captchaError';

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Consider using "reply-to" instead of "from". That way you don't have to deal with spam filters complaining that your from is spoofed, but the reply field will be properly updated when replying to mails.

Comment: Do you mean addreplyto?  I've already got that.  I tried reply-to and it broke my page.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, right. Reply-to being the mail header. So even with addreplyto it doesn't work properly?

Comment: I already have an AddReplyTo.  Do I need two?  I'm lost.

Comment: No, not two. Just wanting to know if it's working properly - if you send the mail, what happens when you reply to it? Do you get the correct recipient in the "to" field of the reply?

Comment: If I click reply in my mail client, the AddReplyTo info is passed int.  However, when I get an email, the From is blank or just says the host company info.  When I had from, it worked, but sent the bounce back to the sender's yahoo address

Comment: Try hard coding the from to something like "no-reply@yourdomain.com" instead of it being a form value.

Comment: I hard coded the yahoo and did not receive it back in the yahoo address through the bcc.  I did get it in my gmail like I have been.  No bounce back message though.

Comment: Usually spam filters will block mails that are from your own address, even when BCC'd. Another option you might consider is using a mail delivery API like Mandrill, or using the SMTP API directly for Yahoo/gmail.